# How to calculate floating interest on loan for banking system

Tags: banking, onlinebanking, core-banking

I am creating a bank loan repayment system, which needs to calculate interest. How can it calculate floating interest rate on a loan account and also flat interest rate on a loan account?

The flat interest rate is *10.25% Interest*. Here is a table of floating interest rates:

> 01/04/2016 - 30/04/2016: 10.25% Interest
>   01/05/2016 - 31/05/2016: 10.00% Interest
>   01/06/2016 - 30/06/2016: 09.50% Interest
>   01/07/2016 - 31/08/2016: 09.60% Interest

The loan amount is *196685.2*
The loan take date is *02/04/2016*
The loan repayment date is the *10th of every month (recurring for 20 months)*.

Give me a formula for how to calculate the interest amount and the principal amount.

Interest added from :

```
02/04/2016 to 10/04/2016,
10/04/2016 to 09/05/2016,

EMI No:.   |  Payment Date  | Beginning Balance  | Principal   | Interest   | Ending Balance
1          |  10/05/2016    | 196685.2           |             |            |               
2          |  10/06/2016    |                    |             |            |               
3          |  10/07/2016    |                    |             |            |               
4          |  10/08/2016    |                    |             |            |
```

I need a formula for the interest, principal and EMI calculation using ASP.NET with C# as the programming language.

Comment: We might help out if you'd made some effort and demonstrated where you're stuck. As it is, this seems to be "do the necessary research and write my code for me" - do *we* get you salary/course credit if we answer?

Comment: I have improved the presentation of your question to make it more readable. However, your question doesn't really belong on this site; you don't seem to have even started the coding, and are asking for a financial/accounting formula for calculating interest amounts.